# Defining functions with special cases

Tags: function-construction

I'm trying to define a function `myFunc` with a special case:

```
myFunc[x_, y_] = (x^2 - y) Log[x^2 - y];
myFunc[x_, x_^2] = 0;
```

This seems to work in limited cases only:

```
In[1] := myFunc[x, x^2]
Out[1] = 0
```

But if I put in numbers, or anything else, it fails.  How would I fix this?

```
In[2] := myFunc[2.1, 2.1^2]
Out[2] = Indeterminate

In[3] := myFunc[a^2, a^4]
Out[3] = Indeterminate
```

I am more interested in making case with numbers to work.  What should I do?

Comment: Patterns are not a good way to define functions with special cases, see my comment and answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try:

```
myFunc[x_, y_] := (x^2 - y) Log[x^2 - y];
myFunc[x_, y_] := 0 /; y == x^2;

{myFunc[2.1, 2.1^2], myFunc[a^2, a^4]}
(*
-> {0,0}
*)
```

Comment: +1 This definitely achieves what was asked (even though the example function doesn't really need a case distinction).

Comment: Perfect!  Upon further usage, I discovered that I should define the special cases before the general function for this to work fool-proof.  Can you verify/comment on this?

Comment: @QuantumDot Sorry, but I'm not sure about how Mathematica does the prioritization of pattern testing. Perhaps that is a good question ... if it wasn't asked before :)

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is not that the function needs to have a special value at a certain point, because the function is in fact continuous at the point you're trying to single out. The only problem is that *Mathematica* isn't calculating the limit $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\epsilon\ln(\epsilon) = 0$ when it should.

Instead of singling out the offending point by pattern matching, I would take the more mathematically motivated route of specifying that a limit exists and should be taken:

```
Clear[myFunc]
myFunc[x_, y_] := Limit[d Log[d], d -> x^2 - y];
myFunc[4, 4]
(* ==> 12 Log[12] *)
myFunc[4, 16]
(* ==> 0 *)
```

Now you don't need any case distinctions at all.

**Edit**

Looking at the other solutions, one thing came to mind that was missing if you *do want* to make a case distinction (i.e., if you had a different function in your example that requires it):

Clearly you want

```
myFunc[a^2, a^4] == 0
```

But what about this?

```
myFunc[a^2, b^4] /. b -> a
```

Strictly speaking, all definitions including mine from above make a potential mistake here in assuming that `a` and `b` are different when returning a result from `myFunc`, so that if you *subsequently* set `b -> a` you get an error from the $0 \times \ln 0$ expression.

To circumvent that, it might be best to insist on keeping the result of `myFunc` **conditional** if it gets symbolic parameters. Then you could instead define it like this:

```
Clear[myFunc];
myFunc[x_, y_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(x^2 - y) Log[x^2 - y], x^2 != y}, {0, True}}];
myFunc[2, 4]
(* ==> 0 *)
myFunc[a^2, a^4]
(* ==> 0 *)
myFunc[a^2, b^4]
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  \left(a^4-b^4\right) \log \left(a^4-b^4\right) &
>    a^4\neq b^4 \\
>  0 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

Now the result of the last symbolic input is the unevaluated `Piecewise` expression, and consequently we can move on without fear, getting the correct result if we later look at the problematic special case:

```
myFunc[a^2, b^4] /. b -> a
(* ==> 0 *)
```

Again, in your specific case that's not the best approach because you can use a limiting process to define the function.

Comment: Your second solution involving `Piecewise` is particularly useful to me since the problem I have at hand is a function involving 3 argument with lots of different `Log`'s which have many limiting cases.

Comment: @QuantumDot If the answer is useful to you ... vote it up :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the function to Hold:

```
SetAttributes[myFunc, HoldAll];
myFunc[x_, y_] = (x^2 - y) Log[x^2 - y];
myFunc[x_, x_^2] = 0;

myFunc[2.1, 2.1^2]
0
```

But this is not a "robust" approach without further fiddling. For example:

```
myFunc[5, (2+3)^2]
Indeterminate
```

Comment: This may not be mathematically robust but it is the desired pattern and the way I would approach this myself. +1

Comment: This will fail for example for `myFunc[Sin[Pi/4], 1/2]`